# Does Azure Digital Twins support geospatial queries?

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

Does Azure Digital Twins support geospatial queries? I'm evaluating using Azure Digital Twins in an upcoming project and am looking to verify if there is a way to query twins by proximity on a coordinate system. With DTDLv2, I understand that Properties do not support arrays so Point and geometry types are only available for Telemetry. I will want to persist lat/lon locations, so I was thinking I would create a Property that was an object with lat/lon fields.

Because of that limitation of no arrays on Properties, I'm guessing there's no geospatial query support but was looking to verify my suspicions. If that's the case, are there other techniques or Azure services that would help with geospatial analysis to use along with Azure Digital Twins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not supported today, as you suspected, but we will be exploring for future releases